# Managed Oracle Client with Oracle Advanced Security Options

Tags: .net, oracle, entity-framework-6, odp.net, oracle12c

On October 14th, Oracle release the latest version of their Oracle Managed Client which was described to support Network Data Encryption.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/tech-info/odac12cr4ds-2704217.pdf
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.ManagedDataAccess/

Although for some reason after trying multiple configuration, we still weren't able to get it to work. We keep getting the infamous `ORA-12570: Network Session: Unexpected packet read error` exception wrapped in `The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string`. The error in the alert log is the following `TNS-12599: TNS:cryptographic checksum mismatch`

We did confirm with the DBA that we were using the supported encryption algorithm.

At this point, my only additional settings are the following:

```
  <settings>
    <setting name="SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES" value="NTS" />
    <setting name="NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH" value="LDAP,tnsnames" />
  </settings>
```

Comment: Check the alert log on the database server. Is an ORA- error being reported there at the time you try to connect? If so, please report the full error here.

Comment: @ChristianShay Original post updated

Comment: Someone recently reported this on the Oracle forums and they found a way around it by modifying some SQLNET.ORA server side settings..have a read and see if it helps you resolve this: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3823310

Comment: Verified the cause of your problem. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: Upgrade to ODP.NET Managed 12.2 or later. Support for data integrity algorithms was introduced there: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E85694_01/ODPNT/featConnecting.htm#ODPNT8536

ODP.NET, Managed Driver 12.1 and earlier did not yet support data integrity algorithms:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63268/featConnecting.htm#CJAGFFCA

This leads to the TNS-12599: TNS:cryptographic checksum mismatch error in your database alert log which in turn causes various client side errors such as ORA-12570: Network Session: Unexpected packet read error or ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file.

If you are forced to use ODP.NET managed version 12.1 and cannot upgrade to 12.2 or later, this can be fixed by changing database side SQLNET.ORA parameters, such that checksums are not REQUIRED:

sqlnet.crypto_checksum_client = ACCEPTED

sqlnet.crypto_checksum_server = ACCEPTED

Comment: you will also need to remove those encryption types for the server as well, they need to match...OR you can use the unmanaged drivers for now

Comment: My answer was to change "database side SQLNET.ORA parameters".

Comment: It is supported now with ODP.NET Managed 12.2. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E85694_01/ODPNT/featConnecting.htm#ODPNT8536