# ODP.NET Oracle.ManagedDataAcess random ORA-12570 errors

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net, managed, oracle12c

I'm trying to migrate to Oracle.ManagedDataAcess from unmanaged version and receiving randoms ORA-12570 TNS:packet reader failure.

I don't know why this error starts, but once it starts, every subsequent request gives the same error for about 10-30 minutes, then it works again for another 10-30 minutes and so on.

So it is a random of subsequent failures for some time then subsequent success

Already tried a lot of things, to resume:

**The environment:**

- Oracle.ManagedDataAcess version 12.1.2400 (4.121.2.20150926) (nuget) (no gac reference installed on server that could override the bin version)
- Oracle Server Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
- Windows 2012 (Windows Update ok)

**Checked:**

- Firewall: It is not a firewall problem
- Machine error: The same problem happens on my machine, Azure WebApp and an AWS EC2 Instance
- Interference: There is no sniffer running, transparent proxy etc.
- Encryption: I don't use any kind of encryption (unless there is something enabled by default that I don't know)
- Connections string: The same connection string is working perfectly with the unmanaged version

**Aditional information:**

- This is a production database, it is very stable
- The application is compiled to anycpu, the IIS app pool is restricted to 64bits
- Im testing exactly the same request every time (just a refresh on a get url of a rest ws, webapi), so it is not related to data format

**Configuration:**

**Server sqlnet.ora**

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

**Application Web.config**

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="XXXX" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxx.xxx.com)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=xxx)));User Id=xxxxx;Password=xxxxx;" />
</connectionStrings>

<configSections>
    <section name="oracle.manageddataaccess.client" type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
</configSections>

<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
      <dataSources>
        <!--<dataSource alias="SampleDataSource" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=ORCL))) " />-->
      </dataSources>
      <settings>
        <setting name="SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES" value="NONE"/> <!--NTS-->
        <setting name="sqlnet.crypto_checksum_server" value="rejected"/>
        <setting name="sqlnet.crypto_checksum_client" value="rejected"/>
        <setting name="SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER" value="rejected"/>
      </settings>
    </version>
</oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
```

**Some references:**

https://community.oracle.com/thread/3634263?start=0&tstart=0

[ODP.net managed driver throws ORA-12570: Network Session: Unexpected packet read error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122395/odp-net-managed-driver-throws-ora-12570-network-session-unexpected-packet-read)

[Managed Oracle Client with Oracle Advanced Security Options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33671090/managed-oracle-client-with-oracle-advanced-security-options)

[ODP.NET error in IIS: ORA-12357 Network Session End of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33395963/odp-net-error-in-iis-ora-12357-network-session-end-of-file)

**UPDATE 1**

After pooling changed (as I described as an answer here), I decided to publish a version to do some real test. After 1 day and users complaining about performance I got another error: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: byteArray

I changed the reference back to the unmanaged version and everything was fine again, faster, without bytearray error, better pooling management.

So I'm just giving up of the managed version for now, maybe I will try again on Oracle next release.

Here some references about this new error, as you can see, looks like another bug (still without any answer).

https://community.oracle.com/thread/3676588?start=0&tstart=0

[EF + ODP.NET + CLOB = Value Cannot be Null - Parameter name: byteArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593520/ef-odp-net-clob-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-bytearray)

So far, reasons to **not use**:

- Pooling management bug
- CLOB null/not null bytearray errors
- Performance degradation probably related to pooling bug

Comment: Very detailed question, good! May you try with "Pooling=False" in your connection string? I suspect that you have a problem with connection pooling

Comment: @bdn02 Ok I just changed to Pooling=false, now I will wait if the error happens again. Thanks!

Comment: Check the ALERT log on the database side for errors around the same time. Then, research and solve those problems....

Comment: Is this solved? I'm still getting this in 2016! Same components (Oracle Managed Data Access).

Comment: @SuperJMN Not yet. The last version on NuGet is still the same: Last Published: 2015-10-14 | Latest Version: 12.1.2400

Comment: Thanks for suggestion to use unmanaged version, I have no choice too.

Comment: @SuperJMN: See my comment about checking the ALERT log for the same time as the error occurs. That may be key.

Answer (score 14):

In my experience with a similar error 12570 (reader vs writer) there's only one reason for this error - something on your network is terminating idle tcp connections.  Typically this is a firewall/managed switch.  You said you've already ruled out firewall but I'm not sure how.  It's possible that the db itself is terminating the connections (dba script), but I recall that being a different error.

Ora-12571 might be slightly different.  But still since you've identified that the issue is the same in that it's long established pool connections I'll keep going.

There's a couple of things you can do:

1. Set min pool size = 0 in the connection string.  This generally fixes things for me.  It allows the entire pool to be closed out when the app is idle.  There is a small chance though that if your traffic swings violently, decr pool size might need to be increased in order to more quickly close out connections created by a mad rush.
2. Set Expire_Time in sqlnet.ora.  Not obvious by it's name, this setting sends a probe packet, which causes any tcp idle monitoring to be satisfied.  Only issue here is that I'm not entirely sure how to set sqlnet settings with the managed provider.  I'm guessing that sqlnet.ora can go in the exe dir but I'm also seeing some indication that it can be set in the .config in the form of   (see a similar wallet_override example [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3870828?start=0&tstart=0))  Because you're only getting this in the managed provider, I wonder if your unmanaged client sqlnet.ora already has this setting.

I've seen this many times over the years and the first time it happened I created a utility that basically does a binary search to determine the exact timeout time by creating connections of varying durations.  If it consistently lands on the same termination time, you can guess there's a setting somewhere that's causing this.  If it's erratic, then you may have some sort of infrastructure flakiness.

Unfortunately I created it as a c# forms app, so I've pasted both the form code and designer code below:

Form1.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;

namespace TimeoutTest
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    List<TestConnection> connections;
    Int32 connectionCount;
    Int32 multiplier;
    Int32 initialConnectionWait;

    TestConnection controlConnection = null;

    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();



    }

    private void BtStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      connectionCount = Int32.Parse(InConnections.Text);
      multiplier = Int32.Parse(InMultiplier.Text);
      initialConnectionWait = Int32.Parse(InInitialWait.Text);

      DisplayMessage("Starting control connection\r\n");
      controlConnection = new TestConnection();
      controlConnection.ErrorOccured += new EventHandler(controlConnection_ErrorOccured);
      controlConnection.IsControlConnection = true;
      controlConnection.StartTest(2);

      connections = new List<TestConnection>();
      DisplayMessage("Spinning up {0} connections...\r\n", connectionCount);
      for (int i = 0, idleTime=initialConnectionWait; i < connectionCount; i++, idleTime*=multiplier)
      {

        TestConnection connection = new TestConnection();
        connection.Notified += new TestConnection.NotificationEventHandler(connection_Notified);
        connection.ErrorOccured += new EventHandler(connection_ErrorOccured);
        connection.TestCompleted += new EventHandler(connection_TestCompleted);
        connection.StartTest(idleTime);

        connections.Add(connection);
      }
      DisplayMessage("");
    }


    void controlConnection_ErrorOccured(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      DisplayMessage("\r\nControl connection error, aborting!!!");
      BtCancel_Click(this, EventArgs.Empty);

    }

    void connection_TestCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      TestConnection currentConnection = (TestConnection)sender;
      
      if (currentConnection == connections.Last())
        DisplayMessage("\r\nAll tests complete.  Done");
      
    }

    void connection_ErrorOccured(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //stop any active connection.
      foreach(TestConnection tc in connections)
      {
        tc.CompletionTimer.Enabled=false;
      }

      TestConnection currentConnection = (TestConnection)sender;
      Int32 upperTime = currentConnection.IdleTime;
      Int32 lowerTime = 0;
      
      Int32 index = connections.IndexOf(currentConnection);
      //if this is not the first connection...
      if(index > 0)
      {
        //...then set the lower time based on the previous connection
        lowerTime = connections[index-1].IdleTime;
      }

      //get the difference between the lower and upper as the new range to work on
      Int32 range = upperTime - lowerTime;

      
      //divide the range over the number of connections to get the new interval
      Int32 interval = range / this.connectionCount;
      connections.Clear();

      //if the interval is too small try to reduce the number of connections
      while (interval < 2 && this.connectionCount > 2)
      {
        this.connectionCount--;
        DisplayMessage("\r\nConnections too high for current resolution.  Reducing to {0} connections.", this.connectionCount);
        interval = range / this.connectionCount;
      }



      if(interval < 2)
      {
        DisplayMessage("\r\nResolution cannot be increased.  Done.");
      }
      else
      {
        DisplayMessage("\r\nRestarting test with min:{0}, max{1}, resolution{2}.", lowerTime, upperTime, interval);


        //create the new connections
        for (int i = connectionCount-1, idleTime = upperTime-interval; i >= 0; i--, idleTime-=interval)
        {

          TestConnection connection = new TestConnection();
          connection.Notified += new TestConnection.NotificationEventHandler(connection_Notified);
          connection.ErrorOccured += new EventHandler(connection_ErrorOccured);
          connection.TestCompleted += new EventHandler(connection_TestCompleted);
          connection.StartTest(idleTime);

          connections.Insert(0,connection);
        }
        this.connectionCount = connections.Count;
      }

    }
    private void BtCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //stop any active connection.
      foreach (TestConnection tc in connections)
      {
        tc.CompletionTimer.Enabled = false;
        tc.Command.Connection.Close();
      }
      DisplayMessage("Stopped running tests.");
    }


    void connection_Notified(object o, Form1.TestConnection.NotificationEventArgs e)
    {
      DisplayMessage(e.Message);
    }

    private void DisplayMessage(String message)
    {
      DisplayMessage("{0}", message);
    }
    private void DisplayMessage(String message, params Object[] args)
    {
      OutStatus.AppendText(String.Format(message, args) + "\r\n");
    }
    

    public class TestConnection
    {
      public Boolean IsControlConnection { get; set; }
      public OracleCommand Command { get; private set; }
      public Timer CompletionTimer { get; private set; }
      public String ConnectionId { get; private set; }
      public Int32 IdleTime
      {
        get
        {
          return CompletionTimer.Interval / 1000;
        }
        set
        {
          CompletionTimer.Interval = value * 1000;
        }
      }
      #region Events and Delegates
      public event EventHandler ErrorOccured;
      public event EventHandler TestCompleted;
      public class NotificationEventArgs : EventArgs
      {
        public NotificationEventArgs(String message)
        {
          this.Message = message;
        }
        public String Message { get; set; }
      }

      public delegate void NotificationEventHandler(object o, NotificationEventArgs e);

      public event NotificationEventHandler Notified;

      private void Notify(String message)
      {
        if (Notified != null)
        {
          Notified(this, new NotificationEventArgs(message));
        }
      }
      public void Notify(String format, params object[] args)
      {
        this.Notify(String.Format(format, args));
      }



      #endregion

      public TestConnection()
      {
        CompletionTimer = new Timer();
        CompletionTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(CompleteTest);

        Command = new OracleCommand(
          "select 'saddr:' || saddr || '-sid:' || sid || '-serial#:' || serial# || '-audsid:' || audsid || '-paddr:' || paddr || '-module:' || module  from gv$session where audsid=Userenv('SESSIONID')");

        Command.Connection = new OracleConnection(Configuration.OracleConnectionString);
      }

      public String StartTest(Int32 idleTime)
      {
        Command.Connection.Open();
        ConnectionId = (String)Command.ExecuteScalar();
        Notify("Started test with idle time={0}, id={1}.", idleTime, ConnectionId);
        IdleTime = idleTime;
        CompletionTimer.Enabled = true;
        return ConnectionId;
      }

      private void CompleteTest(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        if (!IsControlConnection)
          CompletionTimer.Enabled = false;
        try
        {
          Command.ExecuteScalar();
          Notify("Test complete on connection with idle time={0}, id={1}.", IdleTime, ConnectionId);
          if (TestCompleted != null)
            TestCompleted(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
        catch (OracleException ex)
        {
          if (ex.Number == 12571)
          {
            if (ErrorOccured != null)
            {
              Notify("Found error on connection with idle time={0}, id={1}.", IdleTime, ConnectionId);
              ErrorOccured(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
          }
          else
          {
            Notify("Unknown error occured on connection with timeout {0}, Error: {1}, \r\n{2}",(IdleTime).ToString(), ex, ConnectionId);

          }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          Notify("Unknown error occured on connection with timeout {0}, Error: {1}, \r\n{2}", (IdleTime).ToString(), ex, ConnectionId);
        }
        finally
        {
          if(!IsControlConnection)
            Command.Connection.Close();
        }
      }
    }

    private void InConnections_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Int32.TryParse(InConnections.Text,out connectionCount);
      Int32.TryParse(InMultiplier.Text,out multiplier);
      Int32.TryParse(InInitialWait.Text, out initialConnectionWait);

      OutLongestConnection.Text = (Math.Pow(multiplier,connectionCount-1) * initialConnectionWait).ToString();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      InConnections_TextChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

 }
}
```

Form1.designer.cs:

```
namespace TimeoutTest
{
  partial class Form1
  {
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
      if (disposing && (components != null))
      {
        components.Dispose();
      }
      base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
      this.BtStart = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
      this.OutStatus = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
      this.InConnections = new System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox();
      this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
      this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
      this.InInitialWait = new System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox();
      this.InMultiplier = new System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox();
      this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
      this.BtCancel = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
      this.label4 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
      this.OutLongestConnection = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
      this.SuspendLayout();
      // 
      // BtStart
      // 
      this.BtStart.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 394);
      this.BtStart.Name = "BtStart";
      this.BtStart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
      this.BtStart.TabIndex = 0;
      this.BtStart.Text = "Start";
      this.BtStart.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
      this.BtStart.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.BtStart_Click);
      // 
      // OutStatus
      // 
      this.OutStatus.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 13);
      this.OutStatus.Multiline = true;
      this.OutStatus.Name = "OutStatus";
      this.OutStatus.ReadOnly = true;
      this.OutStatus.ScrollBars = System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Both;
      this.OutStatus.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(766, 375);
      this.OutStatus.TabIndex = 1;
      // 
      // InConnections
      // 
      this.InConnections.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(180, 397);
      this.InConnections.Mask = "00";
      this.InConnections.Name = "InConnections";
      this.InConnections.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(22, 20);
      this.InConnections.TabIndex = 2;
      this.InConnections.Text = "10";
      this.InConnections.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.InConnections_TextChanged);
      // 
      // label1
      // 
      this.label1.AutoSize = true;
      this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(108, 400);
      this.label1.Name = "label1";
      this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(66, 13);
      this.label1.TabIndex = 3;
      this.label1.Text = "Connections";
      // 
      // label3
      // 
      this.label3.AutoSize = true;
      this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(289, 399);
      this.label3.Name = "label3";
      this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(113, 13);
      this.label3.TabIndex = 5;
      this.label3.Text = "Initial Connection Wait";
      // 
      // InInitialWait
      // 
      this.InInitialWait.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(408, 396);
      this.InInitialWait.Mask = "00";
      this.InInitialWait.Name = "InInitialWait";
      this.InInitialWait.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(21, 20);
      this.InInitialWait.TabIndex = 4;
      this.InInitialWait.Text = "60";
      this.InInitialWait.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.InConnections_TextChanged);
      // 
      // InMultiplier
      // 
      this.InMultiplier.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(262, 396);
      this.InMultiplier.Mask = "0";
      this.InMultiplier.Name = "InMultiplier";
      this.InMultiplier.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(21, 20);
      this.InMultiplier.TabIndex = 2;
      this.InMultiplier.Text = "2";
      this.InMultiplier.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.InConnections_TextChanged);
      // 
      // label2
      // 
      this.label2.AutoSize = true;
      this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(208, 400);
      this.label2.Name = "label2";
      this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(48, 13);
      this.label2.TabIndex = 3;
      this.label2.Text = "Multiplier";
      // 
      // BtCancel
      // 
      this.BtCancel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(13, 436);
      this.BtCancel.Name = "BtCancel";
      this.BtCancel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
      this.BtCancel.TabIndex = 6;
      this.BtCancel.Text = "Cancel";
      this.BtCancel.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
      this.BtCancel.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.BtCancel_Click);
      // 
      // label4
      // 
      this.label4.AutoSize = true;
      this.label4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(451, 399);
      this.label4.Name = "label4";
      this.label4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(102, 13);
      this.label4.TabIndex = 7;
      this.label4.Text = "Longest Connection";
      // 
      // OutLongestConnection
      // 
      this.OutLongestConnection.AutoSize = true;
      this.OutLongestConnection.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(559, 399);
      this.OutLongestConnection.Name = "OutLongestConnection";
      this.OutLongestConnection.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(102, 13);
      this.OutLongestConnection.TabIndex = 8;
      this.OutLongestConnection.Text = "Longest Connection";
      // 
      // Form1
      // 
      this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
      this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
      this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(791, 582);
      this.Controls.Add(this.OutLongestConnection);
      this.Controls.Add(this.label4);
      this.Controls.Add(this.BtCancel);
      this.Controls.Add(this.label3);
      this.Controls.Add(this.InInitialWait);
      this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
      this.Controls.Add(this.InMultiplier);
      this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
      this.Controls.Add(this.InConnections);
      this.Controls.Add(this.OutStatus);
      this.Controls.Add(this.BtStart);
      this.Name = "Form1";
      this.Text = "Form1";
      this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Form1_Load);
      this.ResumeLayout(false);
      this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Button BtStart;
    private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox OutStatus;
    private System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox InConnections;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox InInitialWait;
    private System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextBox InMultiplier;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button BtCancel;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label4;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label OutLongestConnection;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your code.I tried with a development server that is on the same network and got the same error, it is a completely different network, OS, Oracle version (11g). The production oracle server is very stable and we never had any problems before, only when managed library is used. Tested with another system too, with nhibernate, same error. It is working now but I'm not satisfied and I will do more test as you suggested here. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have one on my development machine. From all environments that I have tested the production server is the only that have this file. I tried some configurations related with sqlnet.ora with the "oracle.manageddataaccess.client" section of web.config anyway.

Answer (score 7):

After disabling pooling (Pooling=False), as @bdn02 suggested, I could confirm that it worked. However I think it should affect the performance and I was concerned about publishing this code into production without any pooling (I thought the standard values were ok).

So I tried many configurations and looks like somehow (it is not very clear) the pool management of oracle was raising an ORA-12570 error and, after a period of time, the sessions are closed and the application worked again.

To find the best configuration with pooling enabled I created a test application to start 50 threads (each one doing 1 test each 50ms), and decreased the default pool values until the error stoped. This way I was able to get an optimal configuration, stable, without any errors.

Obviously it does not applies to every server, but this is my final connection string configuration:

```
Pooling=true;Min Pool Size=1;Connection Lifetime=180;Max Pool Size=50;Incr Pool Size=5
```

Comment: Seems to be a bug in ODP.NET Managed driver (it is still quite new and has some bugs). I recommend to open also a ticket at Oracle support.

Comment: Yes, with Pooling disabled the application is slow. Another option that you can check is to add "validate connection" attribute in the connection string

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit If changing the Pooling attributes can solve this, I would not say it's necessarily all the ODP .NET driver's fault, but the database's ability to handle multiple threads. Other connections than that made by the ODP driver also take up the DB's attention, and pooling is supposed to handle that. If it is not, that is a flaw on the DB side, not necessarily the driver that is used to connect to the DB, unless  a single app is somehow overloading the DB by being too fast or pushing too many threads at once (higher pool size than DB can handle). Then it would be the driver.

Comment: @vpacguy The database's ability to handle multiple threads can be configured, but doesn't matter how big it is, if the drive have a bug that is consumming pools in a completely wrong way, the database will not have any choice than protect itself closing further connections. I did this test, I increased the size of the pool twice the default value, and the result was that the time for that error to show up was increased about 1 hour. The native driver by the way worked pretty well with very low pooling limit configured. So, it is a bug on managed driver.

Comment: I'd go min pool size = 0 instead of 1.  That one connection left overnight could still be terminated and then it is dead in the morning.

Answer (score 1):

I give you a powershell script that i use to check the database connectivity.

`$baselogpath = ""
$filesuffix = "_GetDBConnection"
$dbuser      =""
$dbpassword  =""
$dbalias     = "";
    $command = new-Object Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand($queryString, $connection);
    $connection.Open();
    $count = $command.ExecuteScalar();
    $connection.Close();

    $message = "Records found: " + $count;
    $esito = "OK";
}
Catch
{
    $message = $_.Exception.Message;
    $esito = "KO";
}
$now = Get-Date
$filename = $baselogpath + $now.Year + $now.Month.Tostring("00") + $now.Day.Tostring("00") + $filesuffix + ".log"
if (!(Test-Path($filename)))
{
    $fileheader = "Time     Esito, Elapsed, Message"
    $fileheader > $filename
}
$Time.Stop();
$Elapsed = $Time.Elapsed;
$row = $now.Hour.toString("00") + ":" + $now.Minute.toString("00") + ":" + $now.Second.toString("00") + " "  + $esito + "," + $Elapsed.Hours.toString("00") + ":" + $Elapsed.Minutes.toString("00") + ":" + $Elapsed.Seconds.toString("00") + "," + $message;
$row >> $filename`

Can you try to schedule this script every one minute, using the managed version of Oracle managed dll?
I would understand if the problem is only on web application or if is oracle managed driver related.
You you would to make an advanced test, you may schedule a copy of this script that use the unmanaged version of oracle.dataaccess.

Good luck

Comment: I did a similar test but with a windows forms application, not scheduled, but got the same errors as web application. I will make some changes to loop and log the test just as your script does. But.... no errors after Pooling=False so far... I will schedule this test while I wait. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same intermittent error using SQL Server Reporting Services 2016 with ODAC 12c Release 4:

```
Error:
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted) 
Query execution failed for dataset 'TermPrompt'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand) 
ORA-12570: Network Session: Unexpected packet read error 
ORA-12570: Network Session: Unexpected packet read error 
ORA-12537: Network Session: End of file
```

Adding the pooling parameter `Data Source="myOracleDB";Pooling="false"` to the Oracle data source in SSRS completely resolved the problem.

An immediate re-execution of the report works fine.

I realize there are potential performance issues in creating a new connection each time rather than using the pool, but until Oracle fixes this, I don't want my users encountering this error.

Comment: Exactly as observed on others answers / comments. We got a 30% performance degradation disabling pool, so, on my case, it could not be acceptable and I replaced to the unmanaged version back.

Answer (score 1):

There is **KeepAlive** setting, that can prevent pooling errors of loosing connection such as ORA-12571 and similar. (instead of disabling pooling)

The issue and solution:
https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/issues/58

Set `connection.KeepAlive = true;` before opening a connection. You also need to have a version of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Core no lower than 2.19.100 (don't know about not-Core apps).

I had incomprehensible occasional pooling errors in production version "Oracle error ORA-12571  An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host" and "ORA-03135: connection lost contact" with .Net Core 3.0 and the settings helped.

Answer (score 1):

I randomly receive this error for years because my connection can be lost in many ways.
I have put together the solutions that worked for me.

### 1. Keeping the Connection Alive

**1.1 Using KeepAlive Property**
The `KeepAlive` property, when set to `true`, enables the periodic transmission of messages on the connection to prevent idle connections to be dropped. The `KeepAlive` time (the time the connection will remain idle before it sends a keepalive probe) is one minute by default.

**Set KeepAlive on .NET**

```
connection.KeepAlive = true;
```

**1.2 Using EXPIRE_TIME Parameter in client**
The EXPIRE_TIME parameter in the `sqlnet.ora` file determines how frequently the Oracle will search for Dead connections. Setting `EXPIRE_TIME` to 1 means that Oracle checks the connection every minute, this will help to keep the valid connections active.

**In .NET Framework set it on web.config or app.config:**

```
<system.web>
...
<oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
    <version number="*">
        <settings>
            <setting name="TNS_ADMIN" value="C:\Pronet\Config"/>
            <setting name="SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME" value="1"/>
        </settings>
    </version>
</oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
...
<system.web>
```

**In .NET Core:**
.NET Core does not have an equivalent setting. However, you can create a sqlnet.ora file and include the EXPIRE_TIME option in it.

```
SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME = 1
```

Save this file in the TNS_ADMIN folder or in the bin folder for the project.

### 2. Apply a Retry-on-Fail Approach

Implementing a retry-on-fail approach can help handle connection drop issues. This involves writing your code in such a way that it will retry the connection if the initial attempt fails. Here are examples of how to do this:

**2.1 For a standalone method**

```
public string GetData(int retry = 3)
{
    string prop = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        var connectionString = "...";
        using (var conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string sql = "SELECT NAME FROM USERS WHERE ID = 10";

            conn.Open();
            var cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = sql;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                prop = dr["NAME"].ToString();
            }
        }

        return prop;
    }
    catch (OracleException ex)
    {
        //Retry on lost connection errors
        //In tests conducted, the following errors tend to occur when the connection is interrupted between the Open method and the ExecuteReader.
        if (ex.Number == 12570 || ex.Number == 03135 || ex.Number == 12571)
        {
            if (retry == 0)
                throw;

            return GetData(retry - 1);
        }

        throw;
    }
}
```

**2.2 For .NET Framework using Entity Framework**

You can configure an execution strategy to retry when the errors (12571, 12570, 03135, etc..) occur.
Here is a sample in Entity Framework Core:

```
public class RetryOnErrorStrategy : OracleRetryingExecutionStrategy
{
    private static readonly IList<int> ErrorNumbersToRetry = new List<int>()
    {
        12570, 12571, 03135 //lost connection errors
    };

    public SomeRetryStrategy(ExecutionStrategyDependencies dependencies)
        : base(dependencies, DefaultMaxRetryCount, DefaultMaxDelay, ErrorNumbersToRetry)
    {
    }
}

public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    public YourDbContext(string connectionString)
       : base(OracleDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseOracle(new DbContextOptionsBuilder(), connectionString, oracleOptions =>
       {
           oracleOptions.ExecutionStrategy(dependencies =>
               new RetryOnErrorStrategy(
               dependencies));
       }).Options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<SomeEntity> SomeEntity { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       ....
    }
    
    ....
}
```

With the retry-on-fail approach you can do things like:
-Create extension methods to use like ExecuteReaderWithRetry() and ExecuteNonQueryWithRetry() and use them instead of the original methods.
-Create a Class to encapsulate this logic and call it instead of the Oracle Classes.

**References**

[Answer about execution strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70337449/7335274)

[Ora-12570 on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/82946/ora-12570-network-session-unexpected-packet-read-e)

[An issue on GitHub](https://github.com/oracle/dotnet-db-samples/issues/58#issuecomment-744677474)

Answer (score 0):

I was receiving this error in an application exception. There were no more helpful details in the inner exception. Changing the pooling options did not fix the issue, nor did disabling pooling. Once tracing was enabled, it showed a different error "[ORA-12537 network session end of file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847444/odp-net-oracle-manageddataaccess-causes-ora-12537-network-session-end-of-file)" in the trace file (not propagated to the application exception). That thread suggests an old version of the oracle driver is to blame. I checked, and I was using the version from 2014. Upgrading to the 2017/12.2c/12.2.0.1.0 version resolved the issue.