# Randomly getting ORA-12570 and ORA-12571

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-manageddataaccess

I don't know that's going on, but I'm getting this randomly in different parts of my code (wherever I perform a query). I'm using C# .NET and for the connecting to the DB I'm using **Oracle's Managed Data Access**

The server is Oracle 11g.

Maybe this error is produced when there's not enough memory?

Comment: "My car is making a noise, at almost any speed. Please, can you help me? Maybe this is because it rained so much this spring?" I hope you understand what I am saying... you will need to provide more information if you really want us to help. How would YOU answer your own question, with the amount of information you posted?

Comment: Check this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35352060/odp-net-oracle-manageddataacess-random-ora-12570-errors (also to see how to ask good question)

Comment: OK, but I see there's no solution there.

Answer (score 1):

This is typical of a firewall or a switch dropping your connection due to inactivity.  You can check with your network folks, or there are parameters in the database to send pings on the connection level, but they do cause increased network traffic.

[Oracle Database Advanced Security Administrator's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/sqlnet.htm#NETRF209)